# Fortnite 0xc0000078b - Win64 Shipping Error - Normaliz.dll

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I tried updating Fortnite, and now it wont work and gives me an error

```
Fortnite 0xc0000078b - Win64 Shipping Error - Normaliz.dll
```

How can I fix this? I tried "Verifying" the game, but that didnt help?

Answer (score 1):

For me, all I had to do was run Windows Update. I'm on Windows 10, so I could do this by

- Clicking the "Windows" task bar Button in Windows
- Clicking "Settings"
- Clicking "Update and Security"
- Clicking "Windows Update"

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

1) Run "Epic Launcher" as Administrator

or

2) Disable "Real-time Virus Protection"

or

3) Reinstall "Easy AntiCheat"

Usually located at: `C:\Program Files\Epic Games\Fortnite\FortniteGame\Binaries\Win64\EasyAntiCheat`

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem for 2 weeks.

All the advice is rubbish, Easy Anti Cheat is just screwed up, reset it by:

finding EasyAntiCheat folder - search for "EasyAntiCheat_Setup.exe" then delete/rename "Certificates" subfolder and run "EasyAntiCheat_Setup.exe"